# Converting Json to SQL table

Tags: python, mysql, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to learn how to get the following format of json to sql table. I used python pandas and it is converting the json nodes to dictionary.

Same json:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z",
                    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "Device": "/dev/sda1"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "DBJanitor-Private",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DBJanitor",
                "Key": "Owner"
            },
            {
                "Value": "Database",
                "Key": "Product"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DB Janitor",
                "Key": "Portfolio"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DB Service",
                "Key": "Service"
            }
        ],
            "VolumeType": "standard",
            "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
            "State": "in-use",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
            "CreateTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.084Z",
            "Size": 8
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "Attachments": [],
            "VolumeType": "io1",
            "VolumeId": "vol-1234567890abcdef0",
            "State": "available",
            "Iops": 1000,
            "SnapshotId": null,
            "CreateTime": "2014-02-27T00:02:41.791Z",
            "Size": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

until now.. this what I was trying... in python:

```
asg_list_json_Tags=asg_list_json["AutoScalingGroups"]
Tags=pandas.DataFrame(asg_list_json_Tags)
n = []
for i in Tags.columns:
    n.append(i)
print n

engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://user:"+'pwd'+"@mysqlserver/dbname")
Tags.to_sql(name='TableName', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=True)
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue? Why does that code doesn't work?

Comment: so I get an error saying dict cannot be inserted into string

Comment: @DataJanitor, do you want to store __flatten__ data ?

Comment: @MaxU - yup! that is what I want to do

Comment: @DataJanitor, the question is what do you want to do with `Attachments`? For some records it's missing, so we can't use `json_normalize` here, because records without `Attachments` will not be parsed...

Comment: According to what I see, `Attachments` is there for all the records.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
fn = r'D:\temp\.data\40450591.json'

with open(fn) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# some of your records seem NOT to have `Tags` key, hence `KeyError: 'Tags'`
# let's fix it
for r in data['Volumes']:
    if 'Tags' not in r:
        r['Tags'] = []

v = pd.DataFrame(data['Volumes']).drop(['Attachments', 'Tags'],1)
a = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['Volumes'], 'Attachments', ['VolumeId'], meta_prefix='parent_')
t = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['Volumes'], 'Tags', ['VolumeId'], meta_prefix='parent_')

v.to_sql('volume', engine)
a.to_sql('attachment', engine)
t.to_sql('tag', engine)
```

Output:

```
In [179]: v
Out[179]:
                      AvailabilityZone                CreateTime    Iops  Size              SnapshotId      State VolumeType
VolumeId
vol-049df61146c4d7901       us-east-1a  2013-12-18T22:35:00.084Z     NaN     8  snap-1234567890abcdef0     in-use   standard
vol-1234567890abcdef0       us-east-1a  2014-02-27T00:02:41.791Z  1000.0   100                    None  available        io1

In [180]: a
Out[180]:
                 AttachTime DeleteOnTermination     Device           InstanceId     State               VolumeId        parent_VolumeId
0  2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z                True  /dev/sda1  i-1234567890abcdef0  attached  vol-049df61146c4d7901  vol-049df61146c4d7901
1  2013-12-18T22:35:11.000Z                True  /dev/sda1  i-1234567890abcdef1  attached  vol-049df61146c4d7111  vol-049df61146c4d7901

In [217]: t
Out[217]:
         Key              Value        parent_VolumeId
0       Name  DBJanitor-Private  vol-049df61146c4d7901
1      Owner          DBJanitor  vol-049df61146c4d7901
2    Product           Database  vol-049df61146c4d7901
3  Portfolio         DB Janitor  vol-049df61146c4d7901
4    Service         DB Service  vol-049df61146c4d7901
```

Test JSON file:

```
{
    "Volumes": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "Attachments": [
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z",
                    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "Device": "/dev/sda1"
                },
                {
                    "AttachTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:11.000Z",
                    "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef1",
                    "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7111",
                    "State": "attached",
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "Device": "/dev/sda1"
                }
            ],
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Value": "DBJanitor-Private",
                    "Key": "Name"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "DBJanitor",
                    "Key": "Owner"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "Database",
                    "Key": "Product"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "DB Janitor",
                    "Key": "Portfolio"
                },
                {
                    "Value": "DB Service",
                    "Key": "Service"
                }
            ],
            "VolumeType": "standard",
            "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
            "State": "in-use",
            "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
            "CreateTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.084Z",
            "Size": 8
        },
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
            "Attachments": [],
            "VolumeType": "io1",
            "VolumeId": "vol-1234567890abcdef0",
            "State": "available",
            "Iops": 1000,
            "SnapshotId": null,
            "CreateTime": "2014-02-27T00:02:41.791Z",
            "Size": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxU Really appreciate it!. I will plug this in and bug you if any questions

Comment: Beat me to it! Great way of capturing one-to-many with matching Ids for db normalization.

Comment: @DataJanitor, sure, glad i could help

Comment: @MaxU -I was able to successfully implement the code! If I have one more layer of complication how do I tackle it? made changes to the json in the question. Please see the question

Comment: @DataJanitor, you can parse it in the same way as for `Attachments`. NOTE: key `Tags` must be presented in each record, otherwise it won't work properly. Do you have `Tags` in each volume record?

Comment: seeing following error
**   volume_Tags = pandas.io.json.json_normalize(aws_out_to_json['Volumes'], 'Tags' , ['VolumeId'], meta_prefix='parent_')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 847, in json_normalize
    _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 833, in _recursive_extract
    recs = _pull_field(obj, path[0])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 784, in _pull_field
    result = result[spec]
KeyError: 'Tags'**

Comment: here is the code block 
`volume_Tags = pandas.io.json.json_normalize(aws_out_to_json['Volumes'], 'Tags' , ['VolumeId'], meta_prefix='parent_')`

Comment: @DataJanitor, so some records don't have `Tags` key - am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127490/discussion-between-datajanitor-and-maxu).

Comment: @MaxU - I have more question - how do i handle something that is nested further inside Attachments?

Comment: example Tags being nested inside Attachements

Comment: @DataJanitor, i think you should open a new question with a reproducible sample JSON file. This one has already been "overloaded"...

Comment: here is the new post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40454898/nest-in-a-nest-json-model-to-sql-table[link]

Answer (score 2):

Analog to this example: https://github.com/zolekode/json-to-tables/blob/master/example.py

Use the following script:

The following script exports the data as HTML, but you might as well export it as SQL.

```py
table_maker.save_tables(YOUR_PATH, export_as="sql", sql_connection=YOUR_CONNECTION)
# See the code below
```

```
import json
from extent_table import ExtentTable
from table_maker import TableMaker

Volumes = [
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "AttachTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z",
                "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
                "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
                "State": "attached",
                "DeleteOnTermination": "true",
                "Device": "/dev/sda1"
            }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "DBJanitor-Private",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DBJanitor",
                "Key": "Owner"
            },
            {
                "Value": "Database",
                "Key": "Product"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DB Janitor",
                "Key": "Portfolio"
            },
            {
                "Value": "DB Service",
                "Key": "Service"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeType": "standard",
        "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
        "State": "in-use",
        "SnapshotId": "snap-1234567890abcdef0",
        "CreateTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.084Z",
        "Size": 8
    },
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Attachments": [],
        "VolumeType": "io1",
        "VolumeId": "vol-1234567890abcdef0",
        "State": "available",
        "Iops": 1000,
        "SnapshotId": "null",
        "CreateTime": "2014-02-27T00:02:41.791Z",
        "Size": 100
    }
]

volumes = json.dumps(Volumes)
volumes = json.loads(volumes)

extent_table = ExtentTable()
table_maker = TableMaker(extent_table)
table_maker.convert_json_objects_to_tables(volumes, "volumes")
table_maker.show_tables(8)
table_maker.save_tables("./", export_as="html") # you can also pass in export_as="sql" or "csv". In the case of sql, there is a parameter to pass the engine.
```

Output in HTML:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>AvailabilityZone</th>
      <th>VolumeType</th>
      <th>VolumeId</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>SnapshotId</th>
      <th>CreateTime</th>
      <th>Size</th>
      <th>Iops</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>us-east-1a</td>
      <td>standard</td>
      <td>vol-049df61146c4d7901</td>
      <td>in-use</td>
      <td>snap-1234567890abcdef0</td>
      <td>2013-12-18T22:35:00.084Z</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>us-east-1a</td>
      <td>io1</td>
      <td>vol-1234567890abcdef0</td>
      <td>available</td>
      <td>null</td>
      <td>2014-02-27T00:02:41.791Z</td>
      <td>100</td>
      <td>1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>PARENT_ID</th>
      <th>is_scalar</th>
      <th>scalar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>AttachTime</th>
      <th>InstanceId</th>
      <th>VolumeId</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th>DeleteOnTermination</th>
      <th>Device</th>
      <th>PARENT_ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z</td>
      <td>i-1234567890abcdef0</td>
      <td>vol-049df61146c4d7901</td>
      <td>attached</td>
      <td>true</td>
      <td>/dev/sda1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>PARENT_ID</th>
      <th>is_scalar</th>
      <th>scalar</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>False</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Value</th>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>PARENT_ID</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>DBJanitor-Private</td>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>DBJanitor</td>
      <td>Owner</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Database</td>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>DB Janitor</td>
      <td>Portfolio</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>DB Service</td>
      <td>Service</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The question was how to convert to SQL, not HTML tables.

Comment: @szeta that is a bit unfair don't you think? Did you see this line of code above ? 
```table_maker.save_tables("./", export_as="html") # you can also pass in export_as="sql" or "csv". In the case of sql, there is a parameter to pass the engine.
```

I said export can be anything from html to sql. The HTML table output was to provide visuals. I hope you reconsider your vote.

Comment: I did not see this comment. To avoid this in the future I would recommend to highlight those points better. The most relevant bit to answer the question was (is!) hidden deep in a comment and far from obvious. If you edit the answer, I will revoke the downvote. (it is now blocked until edited)