# Nest in a Nest Json model to SQL Table

Tags: python, mysql, json, pandas

here is an example json. Previously, I was able to solve for Attachments and tags not being nested and as induvidual columns. Any help is deeply appreaciated!

```
{
    "Volumes": [{
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1a",
        "Attachments": [{
            "AttachTime": "2013-12-18T22:35:00.000Z",
            "InstanceId": "i-1234567890abcdef0",
            "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
            "State": "attached",
            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
            "Device": "/dev/sda1",

            "Tags": [{
                "Value": "DBJanitor-Private",
                "Key": "Name"
            }, {
                "Value": "DBJanitor",
                "Key": "Owner"
            }, {
                "Value": "Database",
                "Key": "Product"
            }, {
                "Value": "DB Janitor",
                "Key": "Portfolio"
            }, {
                "Value": "DB Service",
                "Key": "Service"
            }]
        }],
            "Ebs": {
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901",
                                "AttachTime": "2016-09-14T19:49:11.000Z"
                            },
        "VolumeType": "standard",
        "VolumeId": "vol-049df61146c4d7901"
    }]
}
```

Comment: updated with correct json

Comment: got it - please check updated answer!

Comment: Started working on it and hit a snag with a new record being added to the json :( I have updated the json in the question. can you please take a look?

Comment: still need guidance with this. Any help is highly appreaciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [1]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\40454898.json'

In [2]: with open(fn) as f:
   ...:     data = json.load(f)
   ...:

In [14]: t = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['Volumes'],
    ...:                               ['Attachments','Tags'],
    ...:                               [['Attachments', 'VolumeId'],
    ...:                                ['Attachments', 'InstanceId']])
    ...:

In [15]: t
Out[15]:
         Key              Value Attachments.InstanceId   Attachments.VolumeId
0       Name  DBJanitor-Private    i-1234567890abcdef0  vol-049df61146c4d7901
1      Owner          DBJanitor    i-1234567890abcdef0  vol-049df61146c4d7901
2    Product           Database    i-1234567890abcdef0  vol-049df61146c4d7901
3  Portfolio         DB Janitor    i-1234567890abcdef0  vol-049df61146c4d7901
4    Service         DB Service    i-1234567890abcdef0  vol-049df61146c4d7901
```

NOTE: second argument `['Attachments','Tags']` is a path to to our nested record (`data['Values']->Attachments->Tags`) and third argument `[['Attachments', 'VolumeId'], ['Attachments', 'InstanceId']]` is a *path* to outer metadata (`data['Values']->Attachments->VolumeId`, `data['Values']->Attachments->InstanceId`)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... I started trying it and I have hit one more snag :( updated the json in the question

Comment: I still need guidance with this. Any help is highly appreaciated!

Comment: @DataJanitor, i've answered about `Ebs` in [your new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40456418/how-to-convert-multiple-layers-of-nested-json-to-sql-table) - please check