# How to map kafka consumer data to Mysql using python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

My host configuaration is as follows:

Kafka,
Spark,
Mysql ,
are on docker

My code is as follows:

```
# To find out where the pyspark
import sys
from kafka import KafkaProducer,KafkaConsumer
import findspark
from boto3 import *
import boto3
import json

findspark.init()
# Creating Spark Context
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
def get_connection(self):
     spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("SparkByExamples.com").getOrCreate()  
     return spark   

def json_serializer(data):
     return json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8")
    

def read_s3():
    p1 = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['broker:29092'], value_serializer=json_serializer)
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('kakfa')
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        key = obj.key
        body = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    p1.send("Uber_Eats",body)
    p1.flush()
def read_from_topic(self,spark):
    df = spark.readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker:29092") \
        .option("subscribe", "Uber_Eats") \
         .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
    df2 = df \
        .writeStream \
        .format("console") \
        .start()
    print(df2.awaitTermination()  )  
def get_consumer(self):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer("Uber_Eats", group_id='group1', bootstrap_servers=
    "broker:29092",value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))
    return  consumer   
def print_details(self,c1):
    for msg in c1:
          print(msg.value)
    print("Dom  dfe")            
           
          
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
                 
        spark = get_connection(self)
        read_s3()
        # System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "$HADOOP_HOME\winutils-master\hadoop-2.x.x")
        c1 = get_consumer(spark)
        print_details(self,c1)


f = Foo()
```

My output from above code is as folows:

```
{
    
        {
            "Customer Number": "1",
            "Customer Name": "Shyam",
            "Restaurant Number": "2201",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Bawarchi",
            "Number of Items": "3",
            "price": "10",
            "Operating Start hours": "9:00",
            "Operating End hours": "23:00"
        },
        {
            "Customer Number": "2",
            "Customer Name": "Rohini",
            "Restaurant Number": "2202",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Sarvana Bhavan",
            "Number of Items": "4",
            "price": "20",
            "Operating Start hours": "8:00",
            "Operating End hours": "20:00"
        },
        {
            "Customer Number": "3",
            "Customer Name": "Bhairav",
            "Restaurant Number": "2203",
            "Restaurant NameOrdered": "Taco Bell",
            "Number of Items": "5",
            "price": "30",
            "Operating Start hours": "11:00",
            "Operating End hours": "21:00"
        }
    
}
```

How do I read this to columns into mysql?
i) Is it like a regular json file , read and insert?

ii)Or Do we have anything kakfa consumer  'json' format specific?

iii) I have specified value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

in code to get in json format is this necessary to load data into mysql

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: In order to send data from kafka to another system or send data from another system to kafka you can use kafka-connectors

Comment: Here is a link that might help you start: https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-mysql-sink.html

Answer (score 0):

> Is it like a regular json file , read and insert?

Not sure what you mean by this. Mysql doesn't accept json files

Spark has its own JSON file reader, but you're reading from Kafka, so that's irrelevant

> Do we have anything kakfa consumer 'json' format specific?

Yes. `CAST(value as STRING)` followed by various `get_json_object` calls. I've already linked you to this [Databricks blog series](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html)

> I have specified value_deserializer=lambda x: json.loads(x.decode('utf-8')))

This isn't Spark. I'm not sure why you still have this. Secondly, `def get_consumer(self)` doesn't accept or use the `spark` variable you've passed it, and you have no class definition there, so using `self` as the parameter named is discouraged (in other words, all your functions should be within `class Foo`, but you also don't really need classes at all)

**Important detail** - The file you've shown is not valid JSON, so none of these methods are going to immediately work, anyway

**tl;dr** - assuming you actually want to use Spark

1. Use the function you've written that uses Spark consumer
2. Replace

```
df \
  .writeStream \
  .format("console") \
```

With a [JDBC writer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), `.writeStream.format("jdbc").save("jdbc:mysql//…")` but only after your dataframe is modified to match the database schema

---

Otherwise, if you don't want Spark anymore, then JSON or Kafka is an implementation detail - download and configure a Mysql python client, then insert data like normal - being careful about transactions, rollbacks, error handling, prepared queries, etc

---

Or, as answered and commented several times, and **more fault tolerant** solution, forget Python and use Kafka Connect (scripts available in your Kafka bin directory, and requires no coding)

Comment: No I am not trying to use spark streaming, I am getting output through Kafka consumer and form there i am trying to enter into mysql

Comment: You have also specififed this is not valid JSON format, can you please show how valid fomrat looks , I will change accordingly

Comment: Then why are you calling `spark = get_connection(self)`? Or using Spark code at all? Put your data here, it'll tell you what's wrong (you're outer most brackets should be `[]` or you need keys for each value in that object) https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ Other than that (assuming your print details function actually works, but I don't think it does due to other syntax issues), like I said, Kafka really doesn't matter here. Make a simpler script that starts with a list of JSON strings and parse/write them to mysql; once you have that working well, replace that list with your consumer

Comment: Plus, since Kafka is an implementation detail, there's plenty of other questions showing exactly what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251124/inserting-json-into-mysql-using-python or with pandas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40450591/converting-json-to-sql-table